# GDAL raster attribute table not opening on python3.6 and GDAL 2.1.3

Tags: python, gdal

This is related to the question at [Different results from GDAL raster attribute table command on mac and windows](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/192356/different-results-from-gdal-raster-attribute-table-command-on-mac-and-windows)

Now, I am not able to get the raster attribute table of the same file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/fmomfpro3j6dmz8/Shift_cult_past_current_prediction_20160107_gr1DD.tif?dl=0 on windows. I am using python 3.6 and gdal version 2.1.3. The code is as follows:

```
import gdal
dataset = gdal.Open(dataset_uri) # dataset_uri is path to .tif file
band = dataset.GetRasterBand(1)
rat = band.GetDefaultRAT()
```

--EDIT:

how to get the raster attribute table usingpython 3.6 and gdal 2.1.3

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: thanks @LoganByers, the question is how to get the raster attribute table usingpython 3.6 and gdal 2.1.3. Sorry, I should have been clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

# create a Raster Attribute Table(RAT), then create needed columns

```
rat = gdal.RasterAttributeTable()
rat.CreateColumn("Value", gdalconst.GFT_Integer, gdalconst.GFU_MinMax)
rat.CreateColumn("Count", gdalconst.GFT_Integer, dalconst.GFU_PixelCount)
rat.CreateColumn("Red", gdalconst.GFT_Integer, gdalconst.GFU_Red)
rat.CreateColumn("Green", gdalconst.GFT_Integer, gdalconst.GFU_Blue)
rat.CreateColumn("Blue", gdalconst.GFT_Integer, gdalconst.GFU_Red)
rat.CreateColumn("Class_Name", gdalconst.GFT_String, gdalconst.GFU_Name)

# populate the columns
for i in range(256):
    stringValue = str(i)
    intValue = int(i)
    bandhist2 = bandhist[3][intValue]

    rat.SetValueAsInt(intValue, 0, intValue)
    rat.SetValueAsInt(intValue, 1, bandhist2)
    rat.SetValueAsInt(intValue, 2, redDict[stringValue])
    rat.SetValueAsInt(intValue, 3, greenDict[stringValue])
    rat.SetValueAsInt(intValue, 4, blueDict[stringValue])
    rat.SetValueAsString(intValue, 5, classDict[stringValue])

# set the default Raster Attribute Table for src_ds band 1 to the newly modified rat
band.SetDefaultRAT(rat)
```